# getElementsByTagName is not working Simple JS

Tags: javascript

another quesion: http://jsfiddle.net/ajinkyax/qGzTY/1/
Above link shows a js calculator, but whn u click nothign happens

Im just amazed why this simple function not working!!!.

I even tested with a tag, still it wont wokr. getElementsByTagName("a")

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>documentElement</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <p>This is 4rth child (3)</p>
        <p>This is 4rth child (3)</p>

        <p>This is 5th child (4) <span id="some">CHANGE THIS</span></p>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var mySpan = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

            mySpan.innerHTML = 'This is should change';

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you fetch by ID instead?

Comment: A precision : the [basic] tag isn't for trivial problems but for the ones related to the Basic language. That's why I removed it from your question.

Comment: Not so amazing if you do it wrong ;)

Comment: also can u help on this http://jsfiddle.net/ajinkyax/qGzTY/1/

Comment: In fact, I [fixed your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SFA5L/)... a few problems you'll see by comparing with your version.

Comment: but its not working as i wanred, pls review. In my fiddle whn u click nothing happens

Comment: As always, before you use an interface, read its documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this :

```
 var mySpan = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
 mySpan.innerHTML = 'This is should change';
```

`getElementsByTagName` doesn't return an element but a collection of all elements having this tag name. If you want only the first one, add `[0]`.

As was pointed by user1689607, if you want to change just this specific span, you'd better do

```
 var mySpan = document.getElementById('some');
```

Comment: Im adding one more query, please help.

Comment: ur fiddle is added numbers on its own

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't pay attention to the logic. If you can't adapt it (pay attention to "onclick" vs "onClick"), ask another question.

Comment: hey thanx, i renmed onClick to onclick, all works fine now :) http://jsfiddle.net/ajinkyax/qGzTY/2/